# Using SVG to clip (or mask) a DIV

Tags: html, css, svg, mask, clip

I've googled a lot and I've just given up, so I'll turn to the experts out there to see if someone can help me in my quest.

I've got a logo converted to .SVG through illustrator.

My objective is to use that logo to clip (or mask if you prefer) an entire div so that just a small part of it shows through and you can see the background.

I decided to go the .SVG way since I want to create this website as a full scalable experience, and thus a .png would not work accurately from full HD resolutions to 1024x768.

So firstly I would like to know how to clip a Div and at the same time how to "inverse clip" so that instead of just showing that part of the div it would show everything but it.

I'll be eagerly awaiting your answers as I really need them...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: to clarify what you're trying to do...you want to cover and entire div (with a square) and only allow a hole that's the shape of your logo? Does this mean that the logo is a simple path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly (and I'm not sure about that), you want to show 'everything in the background that fits the shape of your logo', is that correct? If though, what about 'inverting' your logo, making itself transparent and give the background a neutral color like black or white or something. Then you could put two divs upon each other, with the top being your Logo.

I created a fiddle to show you what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/ds82/R4rBH/2/

Der circle is the logo and it's transparent inside and outside the blue line and it's a svg. Hope that is what you want.

Comment: Hadn't seen your answer still. It definitely works. Will have to think thoroughly on that and see if it pays up to use that instead of a .png. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to be able to do that.  I once saw a plugin and a generator [like this](http://www.csstextwrap.com/), though I think that that is probably not your best bet.

I would incorporate whatever text you wanted to clip in the svg which I'm sure is easier to do than finding a way for your html to interact properly with the svg.

Comment: i don't think he's interested in wrapping, he probably wants just to visually clip the div

Answer (score 0):

Well since I couldn't do it through .svg I ended up just using a .png where everything is black and my Logo is transparent. Kind of sad that I couldn't find the answer though...

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do works only [in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/mask) at the moment. The way is to define the correct `<mask>` element in SVG and then apply it via CSS:

```
#content {
  mask: url(remote.svg#logo-mask);
}
```

(or, if you embedded the SVG:)

```
#content {
  mask: url(#logo-mask);
}
```