# Centering a div with expandable background image(s) on each side

Tags: html, css, background, center, centering

Is there a way to have two different background images, one attached to each side of a div element, that do not insist on statically appearing when the window is resized smaller?  In other words, if the div element is 900px wide and viewed on a small laptop, it will remain centered but only enough of the left and right backgrounds appear as required by the viewport size.

I think I've exhausted my limited CSS knowledge on this one.

Comment: O! The holy grail of beautiful design / Could be found now in some arcane line? / We ask only for thee to try anew / and consider for divs one, backgrounds, two.

Comment: Well, that's cute, but it doesn't answer my question.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ / Is quite the resource that it sounds / if you loath not the CSS3 / This question is a 'freebie'.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of double/triple/quadruple backgrounds under CSS3, but that isn't the problem. The problem is styling the CSS so that the background(s) will stay attached to a div that's centered, even when the viewport has been reduced to almost the div's width.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must reconsider this Question. There **can only be 1 background**. but You may still give the same effect if required by using **Div's of same dimensions having different backgrounds** on each side of the **Centered** div by floating one to right and other to left. and You may want to Consider having a look on **Jquery Accordion** for Vertical Accordions to give that Effect.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid javascript, assuming there is a remedy with CSS alone.  I've already tried several versions of the method you've suggested, but the problem is that either the extra divs (and their backgrounds) don't attach to the main div.  Worse still, the three divs together have a whopping 1540 total pixel width, and that's the minimum size if you try to resize the browser window.  I'd really prefer that only the main div remains centered in the window as the viewport is decreased.  Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: In that case using SVG is a real good option. You may use Adobe Illustrator to create SVG and that lies below your centered Div and using animate transform from HTML5 you can get certain effects. To know more Google it out. and also see a post [SVG to clip background]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286576/using-svg-to-clip-or-mask-a-div/10288237#10288237

Comment: I've now solved the problem very simply: I created two more divs as you've suggested, but I nested them within the main div which was relatively positioned.  The two additional divs were the same size, but that wouldn't matter.  Rather than insert the two backgrounds as stand-alone images within those divs, I set them in the CSS as true backgrounds.  Finally, rather than floating the divs left and right as you've kindly suggested, I just positioned them absolutely, using negative values on the left and positive values on the right so that they would appear attached to the central div.  Presto!

Comment: ... And I should add that the behaviour I was looking for upon resizing the window is perfect.  I'll remember this for future projects.

Comment: If it is solely for visual purposes I would suggest looking into ::before and ::after. this will prevent adding unneeded markup.